# How to use dynamic date in widget SwiftUI/WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Im using a `Text` view to show a remaining time to a date like so:

```swift
Text(entry.remainingTime, style: .relative)
```

it works but when the timer reaches 0 it start again increasing, which is good for me I just need to know the counter reached 0 so I can change a text, to keep everything understandable until the next widget update happens.

Comment: Look at the widget [code along](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10034/) there are 3 parts I remember there is an example of something similar when the characters reach 100 percent. I don't remember the exact section and term but it doesn't take a long time for see the videos.

Comment: ok I will check that thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget